# How to intercept all read queries to DB in Django?

Tags: python, django, signals

I need to intercept all queries to DB and write them to the file log.
So, if base operations like DELETE, UPDATE and CREATE I can intercept with signals framework. But what about READ queries? How can I catch them with signals?

Comment: this is going to kill your server.

Comment: I don't care, this is a task.

Comment: If a company gives tasks like this, you might want to consider alternative employment. This sort of thing should almost never be done, if it's done at all, it should be at the database level. Edit your question and tag your db

Comment: In an ideal world, mate. But I have what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to create custom middleware, and process queries in it

```
class SQLLoggingMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        from django.db import connection
        for query in connection.queries:
            #... do something with query
```

Answer (score 2):

I think django already does that with it's logging framework. If you want to specifically log only the db queries. 
You can try the following in your settings .

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'query': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/query.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['query'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: "For performance reasons, SQL logging is only enabled when settings.DEBUG is set to True, regardless of the logging level or handlers that are installed."